# How to get value from "token" python requests

Tags: python

i'm tryna only get the value of token:

```
{"token":"v4.public.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJraW1uZTc4a3gzbmN4NmJyZ280bXY2d2tpNWgxa28iLCJjbGllbnRfaXAiOiIxMDkuMTk4LjIyLjEwIiwiZGV2aWNlX2lkIjoiN3J3bDdSU1ZqZFhqQ254aW1Gc0wzcExFeUxXZEsyaGciLCJleHAiOiIyMDIyLTA5LTE3VDAzOjM4OjU0WiIsImlhdCI6IjIwMjItMDktMTZUMTk6Mzg6NTRaIiwiaXNfYmFkX2JvdCI6ImZhbHNlIiwiaXNzIjoiVHdpdGNoIENsaWVudCBJbnRlZ3JpdHkiLCJuYmYiOiIyMDIyLTA5LTE2VDE5OjM4OjU0WiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI1OTYzMTA5NjEifUiOMlr7ILqoLkAgVB_RaWKjuy1rv2pIuFj8rETUtifJCxQonQsJ2qAJsdXDTWBdaVFkKdFMRs4WpXDURNal3AI","expiration":1663385934164,"request_id":"01GD3WZ9AJWRYQDYQ1RRPJX635"}
```

code:

r = requests.post("https://gql.lol.com/integrity", headers=headersin)
print(r.text)

Comment: Step 1: Look at the requests documentation. Step 2: Notice that responses have a .json property... profit?

Comment: r = requests.post("https://gql.lol.com/integrity", headers=headersin).json()

token = r['token']

Answer (score -4):

Simply do:

```py
r.text["tocken"]
```